# ReactJS - Global state outside of components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I've been reading and watching videos on Redux and seeing a lot of debate about managing state in components or with Redux.  What I'm not seeing is anything about managing state completely outside of components with standard global variables.

For example, I could set a global state variable like this:

```
let state = {
   player:  {
       username: "BillyBob",
       score: 100
   }
}
```

Then in a React component, I could have something like this:

```
incrementScore() {
    state.player.score += 1
    props.update()
}
```

Then in App.js, I could have this:

```
update() {
    this.forceUpdate()
}
```

I realize that I'd still have to pass the update function down through the tree, but I'd at least be able to set functions at the component level and not have to worry about passing multiple pieces of state and functions to child components.

I'm new to React, but the only downside I can think of is not being able to require propTypes.  Is there anything else I'm missing?

EDIT:  Per request that I clarify the question, are there any major downsides to the implementation above that I should be considering that would affect even a relatively simple app?

Comment: ask your question so we can answer.

Comment: I think you question is lacking a lot details and I would advice that you go through some more material on [redux](https://medium.com/codingthesmartway-com-blog/learn-redux-introduction-to-state-management-with-react-b87bc570b12a).

Comment: Downsites I could think of: 1) Global state could be modified by other code without updating the UI. 2) Your components are more difficult to test since they are not self contained. 3) Probably doesn't scale well to multiple components.

Comment: One obvious problem is that you are forcing the component and all its child components to update, which isn't an efficient solution. For example, a form has 10 inputs, for every `onChange` event of a single `input`, it will trigger the entire form to re-render.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the implementation of `redux` or some other state management library out there (for example `mobx` or `mobx-state-tree`), basically all of them maintain the state outside of the component as a standalone object.

However, to detect changes and trigger re-render efficiently, they implement a HOC, it's `connect` in `redux` and `inject` in `mobx`, what the HOC (higher order component) does is to wrap your component inside another component that have access to the global `state`, and pass the part of the state require by your component via its props. This way, the component only re-render when the data required by it changes.

Compared with these popular library approach, there are couple problems with your proposed solution.

The first is using `forceUpdate`, basically, the last thing you might want to do is to call `forceUpdate` on the root node of your app, think about scenario when someone type in an input and the whole app re-render every single keystroke.

The second will be passing an `update` function down to multiple level of children, it will be fine if you have only 1 or 2 nested component, but will be a big problem one your app grows. As your app grows and your state become more complex, it might not be the best idea to have a single `update` function to control the whole `state` object.

Comment: Very good point about forceUpdate.  I guess that kind of defeats the purpose of React.

Answer (score 2):

I've created a library exactly for this use case :)

Simple  fast ⚡️ and small  (500 bytes) global state management for React which can be used outside of a React component too!

https://github.com/web-ridge/react-ridge-state

Answer (score 1):

React exists to solve the problem of creating a user interface that is composed of several indepentent pieces that can be developed in parallel and can seamlessly interact with each other.

If you are going to use global namespace to define your state then you are going to bypass most of the key features of React such as:
1. Lifecycle methods
2. Virtual DOM
3. Controlled Components
4. Rendering Optimizations

In a nutshell, you are going to end up with all the overhead costs of running React while missing out on its benefits.

The 'catch' in learning a new framework or paradigm is to understand how to define the problem in such a way that it leads to path of least resistance. This can be achieved by introducing a constraint and then solving the problem within that constraint.

By favoring vanilla JavaScript for state management, you are not giving React and Redux a fair chance.

Comment: The main benefits of React to me are reusability and the ability to calculate certain CSS style elements in line (I actually find it very useful to write calculated, inline CSS at first and then go back and write the regular CSS).  I suppose I could get these benefits with plain JS, however, I’m getting a virtual DOM with React (I don’t see how I’m losing the virtual DOM with global state).  I believe I would lose rendering optimizations and even though that takes part of the essence from React, it might not be a bad tradeoff to some.  I obviously still have a lot to learn about React.

Answer (score -1):

Stick to redux, dont complicate things for yourself :)

Comment: What I have in the question is much simpler than Redux.